# How to do sorting in a text file in c++

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am working on my C++ (File Handling) Project but got stuck on a point

### Here is my .txt file

```
SNO, Name, NoOfPeopleLiked
1, The Shawshank Redemption, 77 
2, The Godfather, 20        
3, Into The Wild, 35
4, The Dark Knight, 55      
5, 12 Angry Men, 44
6, Schindler's List, 33
7, The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King, 25
8, Pulp Fiction, 23
9, The Good, the Bad and the Ugly, 32   
10, The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring, 56
```

I have to display the **top 5 movies** with respect to `NoOfPeopleLiked` Just like that:

### Sample Output

```
1, The Shawshank Redemption, 77
2, The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring, 56
3, The Dark Knight, 55
4, 12 Angry Men, 44
5, Into The Wild, 36
```

so I have to do sorting and this is what I have done so far

---

```
void topFive()
{
    Movies v[20];       //class object array
    fstream top;        //for reading
    top.open("movies.txt");

    for (int h = 0; h < 10; h++) // reading from txt file
    {
        top >> v[h].serial >> v[h].movieName >> v[h].liked; 
    }
    // run loops two times: one for walking throught the array
    // and the other for comparison
    for (int step = 0; step < 5; ++step) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; ++i) 
        {

            // To sort in descending order, change > to < in this line.
            if (v[i].liked > v[i + 1].liked) 
            {

                // swap if greater is at the rear position
                int temp = v[i].liked;
                v[i].liked = v[i + 1].liked;
                v[i + 1].liked = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    //  to print the array
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << v[i].serial << ", " << v[i].movieName << ", " << v[i].liked << endl;
    }
}
```

---

To be Honest I did not know how to do it perfectly I am stucked with this problem for about 6-7 hours and still can't make any logic. I hope you guyz can help me and guide me better. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You want to use `std::sort` here.  You will need to supply a comparison function to it, which can be not much different than your current comparison function.  Alternately if you want to keep rolling your own, you'll need to tell us what you're observing going wrong.

Comment: first you want to read the fields separated by comma and `top >> v[h].serial >> v[h].movieName >> v[h].liked; ` is not the way to do that

Comment: Movie #9 has parsing complications, because the title has a comma in it.

Comment: You could parse the file line by line and apply a regex to each line...

Comment: I appreciate that your code isn't working. But you need to describe how it isn't working as well. Does your vector have reasonable objects in it? Does your sort not sort in the correct order?

Comment: Implemented [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65458876/941531) using standard C++ regular expressions and sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented next solution using [std::regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/regex) module. Plus some strings operations. And of cause sorting!

In my code input file is called `0302.txt`, please rename it to what you need before running code.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow65458745#main.cpp)

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    try {
        auto StrTrim = [](std::string & str){
            str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of("\t\n\v\f\r ")); // left trim
            str.erase(str.find_last_not_of("\t\n\v\f\r ") + 1); // right trim
        };
        std::ifstream ifile("0302.txt");
        std::string line;
        std::vector<std::string> lines;
        // Read all lines of file.
        while (std::getline(ifile, line)) {
            StrTrim(line);
            if (line.empty())
                continue;
            lines.push_back(line);
        }
        if (!lines.empty())
            lines.erase(lines.begin(), lines.begin() + 1); // remove first header line
        lines.erase(lines.begin(), lines.begin() + 1); // remove first header line
        std::vector<std::tuple<size_t, std::string, size_t>> data;
        std::regex re(R"((\d+)\s*,\s*(.+)?\s*,\s*(\d+))");
        for (auto const & line: lines) {
            std::smatch matches;
            if (std::regex_match(line, matches, re)) {
                if (matches.size() != 4)
                    throw std::runtime_error("Matched line with not 3 elements: '" + line + "'!");
                data.push_back(std::make_tuple(size_t(std::stoi(matches[1])), matches[2], size_t(std::stoi(matches[3]))));
            } else
                throw std::runtime_error("Unmatched line: '" + line + "'!");
        }
        std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), [](auto const & l, auto const & r){
            return std::get<2>(l) > std::get<2>(r);
        });
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            if (i >= data.size())
                break;
            std::cout << (i + 1) << "|" << std::get<0>(data[i]) << ", " << std::get<1>(data[i]) << ", " << std::get<2>(data[i]) << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Input file `0302.txt`:

```
SNO, Name, NoOfPeopleLiked
1, The Shawshank Redemption, 77 
2, The Godfather, 20        
3, Into The Wild, 35
4, The Dark Knight, 55      
5, 12 Angry Men, 44
6, Schindler's List, 33
7, The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King, 25
8, Pulp Fiction, 23
9, The Good, the Bad and the Ugly, 32   
10, The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring, 56
```

Console output:

```
1|1, The Shawshank Redemption, 77
2|10, The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring, 56
3|4, The Dark Knight, 55
4|5, 12 Angry Men, 44
5|3, Into The Wild, 35
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just insert the strings from the file inside a vector and sort with a custom comparator function. This comparator function can extract the rank from the input string (assuming the rank is after the last comma, assuming the input schema is uniform) and use it in comparison. Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int get_rank(std::string input) {
    std::stringstream ss(input);
    std::string s;
    // keep extracting strings, last one would be your 'int' rank
    for(; ss >> s; );
    return std::atoi(s.c_str());
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("movies.txt");
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::string line;
    std::getline(infile, line);
    for( ; getline( infile, line ); )
        v.push_back(line);
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](std::string s1, std::string s2) -> bool { return get_rank(s1) > get_rank(s2); });
    for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++)
        cout << i + 1 << "," << v[i].substr(v[i].find(",") + 1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```